# Show that is it impossible to find continuous functions so that the differential equation has unique solutions.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

Show that it is impossible to find continuous functions $ a_1, a_0 : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ so that the differential equation $
x''(t) + a_1(t)x'(t) + a_0(t)x(t)=0 $
has the solution $x(t) = t^2$.

I think its possible to rearrange the equation and show that it won't always be continuous but I think you can also show that the solution(s) violate uniqueness (existence and uniqueness theorem) but I'm not exactly sure how to show this? TIA

Comment: What are $x(0)$, $x'(0)$? What is the solution usually associated to this IVP for a second order linear DE?

Comment: Then, $2 + 2t a_1(t) + t^2 a_0(t) = 0$, for all $t$, including $t = 0$ where we have $2 + 0 + 0 = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

$x''(t)+a_1(t)x'(t)+a_0 x(t)=0$

$x(t)=t^2$.

so from solution $x(0)=0$.

so if substituted back to equation:

$2+2a_1(t)t+a_0(t)t^2=0$

at $t=0$ you get:

$2=0$

so $a_0(t)=O(\frac{1}{t^2})$ for the solution to be valid at $0$.